# Performing verification of teams?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, old-teams

Let's take [this team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/39/google) as an example:

[image]

Based on the team name, a user that comes across this page is very likely to assume that this team is either sanctioned by or managed by Google. (Which may very well be the case with the above example.)

However, **there is no way to know for sure**. I would like to see something similar to what Twitter does with verified accounts:

[image]

Comment: It'd be my first verified checkmark.

Comment: One possibility would be domain verification - teams must verify (through a `<meta>` tag, DNS record, or email to a special address) that they own the domain they claim to represent. Then at least we could be sure that a verified team claiming to use http://google.com really controls that domain.

Comment: and no one has ever hacked a web page before?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't think the responsibility to ensure a website hasn't been hacked falls on Stack Exchange's shoulders.

Comment: did not say that, just saying it is not a 100% valid test of identity.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson right - that's why I stated "Then at least we could be sure that a verified team claiming to use google.com really controls that domain." That doesn't necessarily mean we proved their identity.

Comment: I think if someone was able to take control of google.com a) They would have more interesting things to do with it than steal a Stack Overflow team, and b) it would be in the news.

Comment: How and why is the situation with teams different than with the rest of SO, or SE, for that matter? How do you know that I am [Jörg W Mittag](http://stackexchange.com/users/2172/) and not someone else? Or that this is [Alan Kay](http://stackexchange.com/users/563708/)? Or whether [one](http://stackexchange.com/users/5987957/) [of](http://stackexchange.com/users/5269862/) [the](http://stackexchange.com/users/452360/) [four](http://stackexchange.com/users/331220/) is one of [these](http://pragdave.me/) [two](http://davethomas.net/)? tl;dr: what makes Teams special?

Comment: It's not like we've had this problem before. [Oh wait.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63928/is-this-really-the-bill-gates-or-a-prank-account)

Answer (score 7):

This isn't going to be there just yet in the private beta, but that's indeed on the longer-term roadmap!

Comment: it needs to be there before anything is public for sure because all kinds of negative consequences are just waiting to break loose

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think we'll need to make sure we don't rely *exclusively* on manual verification as a means of communicating authenticity (this wouldn't be very scalable or not available to everyone), but yes, we'll want to have this, at least for the most egregious cases / high profile Teams.

Comment: what happens legally when someone impersonates even a small company or an individual with the will to litigate and causes that other party harm ( financial or otherwise ) ... Just imagine how many lawyers would be all over you for someone impersonating someone and the lawsuit(s) that would kill you guys! And without me knowing it is really a legit team with legit members who are they say they are, what value is this team thing to begin with?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If Teams were meant specifically to represent companies, then yes SO might have some legal liabilities. For now though, the definition is far more general.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Impersonating a small company or an individual is something you could do outside of Stack Overflow (e.g. you could do it on Github, Facebook, etc.). We aren't the only ones facing this problem, but I agree with you we do need to address it : )

Comment: I don’t think we necessarily need verified teams and a verification process if we can keep the number of impersonations low. So if we had a way to flag teams easily as impersonating known entities, we would probably have a fine way to start with.